# Azure Devops CI - Build only tagged commits in specific branch

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

Pushing in the dev branch triggers a build.
But I want only to create a build if the commit in the dev branch has a **tag** with a format of '?.??.??.?'.

```
trigger:
  - dev
```

In the documentation I can only find how to trigger based on a tag **OR** an branch. How can I have two conditions the tag and the commit in the specific branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can use multiple jobs(if your pipeline has multiple jobs you can make use of multiple stages) in your pipeline to achieve above requirement.

Add an additional job(or stage)(ie. Job A)  to get the tags associated to the commit. And then use script check if the tag has a certain format, if not then fail the job. Then and set the other job dependsOn this job. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information about dependenies and conditions

So that your job(ie.Job B) which builds your project will only get executed if the additional job succeeded. Please check below example yaml:

```
trigger: 
  branches:
    include:
      - dev    
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

jobs:     
- job: A
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        #get the tags associated to the commit
        $tags = git describe --exact-match $(Build.SourceVersion) 
        # check the tag format
        if($($tags) -notmatch '.\...\...\..'){exit 1}

- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: succeeded('A')
  steps: 
      - powershell: |
          $tags = git describe --exact-match $(Build.SourceVersion)
          echo $($tags)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - I think there should be multiple conditions possible. This feels more like a hack but should work for now :)